# Overflow Error with copy-pasting Columns in a Nested-loop

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy columns of y-values from a sheet called "Matrix" and paste them into a sheet called "All Normalized", format is not a concern, but the number of columns isn't just 10 but unlimited.

I need to copy the values from Matrix as a column  and divide each cell by the first number in the column to normalize it (first value starts at row 3). And I keep getting this error:"Runtime error '6'- Overflow".

How can I fix this error and properly normalize the data?

```
Sub NewNorm()
Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'X-Values
With WB.Sheets("All Normalized")
[A3].Value = 0
[A4].Value = 1E-18
[A5].Value = 0.0001
[A6].Value = 0.001
[A7].Value = 0.01
[A8].Value = 0.5
[A9].Value = 1
[A10].Value = 2
[A11].Value = 3
[A12].Value = 4
[A13].Value = 5
[A14].Value = 6
[A15].Value = 7
[A16].Value = 8
[A17].Value = 9
[A18].Value = 10
[A19].Value = 20
[A20].Value = 30
[A21].Value = 40
[A22].Value = 50
[A23].Value = 60
[A24].Value = 70
[A25].Value = 80
[A26].Value = 90
[A27].Value = 100
[A28].Value = 150
[A29].Value = 175
[A30].Value = 180
[A31].Value = 185
[A32].Value = 190
[A33].Value = 200
[A34].Value = 300
[A35].Value = 400
[A36].Value = 500
[A37].Value = 1000
End With

Dim ColumnCount As Integer
ColumnCount = 10
Dim Colum As Long

For Columz = 2 To columnz  'Loop through each cell, normalizing
For rowz = 3 To 10
    Sheets("All Normalized").Cells(rowz, Columz).Value = Sheets("Matrix").Cells(rowz, Columz).Value / Sheets("Matrix").Cells(3, Columz).Value 'ERROR HERE
Next rowz
Next Columz

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your narratuive,

> ...divide each cell by the first number in the column ...

Your data,

```
[A3].Value = 0
[A4].Value = 1E-18
[A5].Value = 0.0001
[A6].Value = 0.001
...
```

Your code,

```
Sheets("All Normalized").Cells(rowz, Columz).Value = _
  Sheets("Matrix").Cells(rowz, Columz).Value / Sheets("Matrix").Cells(3, Columz).Value
```

You cannot divide a number by zero. It results in an overflow error.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion. The numbers you see are X-values, the next few columns from B onwards are non-zero whole numbers for Y-values, not shown here. In the loop, it starts the column count from 2, therefore B3, not A3.